# JavaScript stops working after I load another page

Tags: javascript, html, ruby

I am new to JavaScript and trying to see why my on event listeners are not working. I have found similar posts on stackoverflow however the solutions are not working for me.

```
var search = function( event ) {
    alert("bobo")
   $.get("http://localhost:3000/search", {"search" : $("#Search-Bar").val()}, function(data, status){
        if(status == "success")
           $(".centering.text-center").html(data)
    })
}

var attachListeners = function(){
    $("#Search").on("click", search)
    $("#SearchIcon").click( () => search() )
    $("#Search-Bar").keypress( event => (event.KeyCode == 13 || event.which == 13) ? search() : undefined )
}

$(document).ready( function(){ 
    attachListeners()
})
```

My website is not a single page application. I have attached the listeners to my navigation search bar where I load a different view through the nav links and my server(ruby back end) uploads a new html page.

On the first load I have noticed that document ready gets called and everything else works. The on and click. After I use my navigation and load a different html page my events disappear. In my html views my searchbar, searchicon, and a search text have consistent `id`'s through out. I have tried using `window.load()` and putting an onload attribute for my body `<body onload=attachListeners()>` but neither worked(perhaps I didn't use them properly). I also noticed that when I render the next html views my `docment.ready` does not get called. However, if I forcefully refresh the page with an F5 the listeners are active again for that one html page. What am I missing here that I don't understand?

Comment: Just to be clear - do you have this on every page?

Comment: javascript on `page1.html` doesn't run on `page2.html` - all event listeners are gone!

Comment: When I look through my chrome tools and the assets the javascript file is there. If i put a breakpoint on ready or my search function nothing the breakpoint does not work. and the html source code includes my javascript file that has this code.

Comment: Are the javascript functions loaded separately  (via <script src="...."> tags on each page) or is it coded inside each html page?

Comment: It gets loaded in the script tags.  <script src="/assets/jquery3-813eab5befefb6c6b0180297aa0383b0.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs-1e756c23d7c390953250995cfaa04509.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>

Comment: <script src="/assets/search-a5bd7a1975ff160c1e2989a9a077ded4.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>

Comment: What I am noticing its not loading the assets actually. Perhaps its a server side problem? Actually it's strange cause in some cases the chromes tools show the assets there. And in some not there. But even it shows it loaded them for the next page rendered still not working. But it shows the assets are loaded.

Comment: Could you post a more complete version of the codes (including page1.html and page2.html) or maybe a link to test them? There could be issues with other aspects (HTML, other javascripts) so without knowing the other parts, it would likely take quite a while quite to figure things out.

Comment: let me get a heroku app going take me a while. thanks ill post back when i got it up to test

Comment: You might not have disabled [Turbolinks](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#running-javascript-when-a-page-loads) in your application (it's still in your script tags), trying using `document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {` instead of `$(document).ready( function(){`

Comment: Yes dude that worked. Yea I guess I am not sure about what exactly turbolinks does and how that effected it but that suggestion def worked. Thanks man a bunch. If you have time explain! Put it down as an answer and i'll mark it the correct one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might be using [Turbolinks](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks), from the Readme for the project:

> When you follow a link, Turbolinks automatically fetches the page, swaps in its <body>, and merges its <head>, all without incurring the cost of a full page load.

Since this library makes it so the page ever only loads once, normal javascript `window.onload`, `DOMContentLoaded`, and jQuery `ready` events don't function after the initial page load and you have to use

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
```

instead of those. If you're new to turbo links, I suggest reading through that README to see what it's all about.

I've never understood why the Rails team would put something like this in rails and enable it by default, and in every single project I've made since they made that change the first thing I do is uninstall it, and when I forgot to do so, I spend several hours later in the project wondering why my javascript is broken.